# Gradle project structure organized different in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I pull a project from github, while the project use the gradle as the build tool, and it contain some sub-projects, then I　tried to import the project to IDEA, this is the procedure:http://pbrd.co/1lMpmyj.

[http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/10QfmWBp.png](http://pasteboard.co/10QfmWBp.png)

As shown, the sub-project are imported as separated project, while I want to keep the fold structure, something like this:http://pbrd.co/1lMpyO6.

Is this possible?

update:

---

gdx/settings.gradle:

```
include ':gdx-core'
include ':gdx-android'
include ':gdx-web'
```

This is the only `settings.gradle` inside the project.

Comment: Sorry, but second screenshot also has subprojects

Comment: The second screenshot is the result I expected....

Comment: Could you try to import settings.gradle?

Comment: I tried that yet, got the same result. I even tried to update to the latest IDEA, and use the `use local gradle distribution` , but none of them worked

Comment: can you share your root settings.gradle and settings.gradle from subfolders if they exist

Comment: I update it in the post.

Comment: It is imported correctly - three subprojects in settings file. I fyou don't have settings in subproject it will take folder name as project name. Do you want to have them different name? Do you want to see only two project instead of three?

Comment: Where is the `gdx` root folder?

Comment: It is there 'gradle -q project' in root folder. I don't know why IDEA doesn't show it because Android Studio does

Comment: In fact, not all the sub gradle modules are android module, some of them are java module.

Comment: It is nothing about android. I just mentioned that Android Studio imports gradle project differently